# Cannot git add my project created with create-react-app

Tags: git, create-react-app

I created a a folder called Tiendas_Unison_WEB in which i have my application, here i have 2 subfolders: client and server.

[image]

In my server folder i have an app created with express and node, this is fine, no problem with that.
In my client folder i have a react app created wit "npx create-react-app" and i'm having issues with this one.
What I did was "git init" on my parent folder "Tiendas_Unison_WEB", but when doing "git add ." I get the following warning: [image]

I've searched for answers and solutions but I haven't been able to find them. I dont know if I should have my client folder and my server folder in different repositories, maybe that's the problem.
Any hint that might help me would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning message tells, that `client` folder itself is already git repository. Open the folder, and check for hidden `.git` file; I guess it will be there. So if you'd like to keep `client` folder as git repository - then add it as `git submodule` to your main repository (for that you need to know its remote address, e.g. url of the git server); or if you do not want it, simply remove `.git` file from the `client` folder.

Comment: I think removing the .git file was a good solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because the react project is itself a git repo
Solutions

1. You can copy all files that you need into another folder and then do `git add .` to add all the changes you made to the repo
2. Or you can delete the git files